# gcc: error: ;: No such file or directory gcc: error: size: No such file or directory

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, directory, filesize

I wanted to know the size of my program, so I typed the following lines
{`gcc EvenOdd.c ; size ./EvenOdd.exe`}
but its giving me the following errors

```
gcc: error: ;: No such file or directory
gcc: error: size: No such file or directory
```

I wanted to know if there is a problem with my syntax or if it's some other issue, and one more thing, I wrote the output file name, should I just write the default ./a.exe

Comment: Which OS do yo use?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the semicolon with &&, that is,

```
gcc EvenOdd.c && size ./EvenOdd.exe
```